# Write a shell script that has a function that displays the number of files in the present working directory, but not subdirectories

Tags: bash, function, subdirectory

Write a shell script that consists of a function that displays the number of files in the present working directory, but not subdirectories

```
# Function to count files in the pwd excluding sub directories 
files_in_pwd() {
    num_files=$(ls -l | wc -l) |  -maxdepth 1
    echo "Number of files in the pwd: $num_files"
}

# Call the function
files_in_pwd
```

Comment: `-maxdepth` is an option to `find`. You can't use it without `find`.

Comment: So, what is your question then? You have posted a script (which, admittedly, does not make sense), but you have not asked anything.

Comment: See [How can I get a count of files in a directory using the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1125/264812).

Comment: Also see [BashFAQ/004 (How can I check whether a directory is empty or not? How do I check for any *.mpg files, or count how many there are?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004).

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` with the `-type f` option to count only regular files, and `-maxdepth 1` to prevent going into subdirectories.

```
files_in_pwd() {
    num_files=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)
    echo "Number of files in the pwd: $num_files"
}
```

Comment: `( d=$(mktemp -d); cd "$d"; touch "$(printf "a\nb\nc")"; files_in_pwd; rm -r "$d" )`

Comment: As @jhnc showed, this does not work correctly when files have newlines in their names.  A standard trick for working around this is: `find .//. -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -c //`

Comment: Lots of things don't work well when filenames have newlines. It's really hard to deal with them in shell scripts. There are tricks like that for particular cases. But unless you're in a context where screw cases like this will cause a problem, I'm happy to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

```
files_in_pwd()(
    shopt -s nullglob dotglob
    any=( * )
    dirs=( */ )
    notdir_count=$(( ${#any[@]} - ${#dirs[@]} ))

    echo "Number of files in the pwd: $notdir_count"
)
```

```
files_in_pwd()(
    shopt -s nullglob dotglob
    n=0
    for e in *; do
        # add appropriate extra tests
        if [[ ! -d $e ]]; then
            (( n++ ))
        fi
    done
    echo "Number of files in the pwd: $n"
)
```

Comment: assumes caller has necessary `rx` permissions on the directory

Comment: These functions leave `nullglob` and `dotglob` set after they return.  That may cause problems elsewhere in a program.  Also, none of the variables are localized, so assigning to them may clobber the values of variables used  elsewhere in the program (possibly leading to lots of debugging fun).  Finally, the `echo` commands may produce incorrect output if `IFS` has an unusual value.

Comment: @pjh shopt and variables shouldn't stay set. it's a subshell

Comment: @pjh ah, got it. thanks, hadn't thought of that issue with echo

Comment: @pjh I like that find trick with `//`. should have realised the question is a duplicate

Comment: I missed the subshell.  Duh.  Sorry.  The question is a duplicate, but almost all of the  answers to duplicates on Stack Overflow contain code that doesn't work in general.  This answer is a rare exception.